# Using JUnit on android project by mocking few android api classes?

Tags: android, junit, mocking

I have some sourcecode in my android project that just uses plain java code.
I created UnitTests (JUnit) for this classes to test them.

The problem is that the functions use internally some android classes yet.
These are Log and Base64 at the moment.

Now I am looking for a simple way to mock this Classes but I was not able to do so.

I googled and found a lot of mocking tools like jmocking, mockito, robolectric and so on, but I am very confused with this libraries and did not get one of them to work.

I did not find one good step by step tutorial that shows me how to simply mock some android class so I do not get this stub / classnotfound errors.

Questions would be:

- What is the most common used android mocking library?
- How do I mock some Class that I do not use directly in my UnitTest, but that are used by the functions I call?

Thanks,
Subby

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that any mocking library will fully support Android. There are several technical reasons why Android and mocks don't get along.

If you want to unit test a java object that uses the Android API, you usually have to use one of the test case classes in android.test.*. Android classes often need an Android context in order to work correctly.

For a unit test, you usually inject a dependency, but there are limits. After all, you don't unit test the multiplication operation! You can unit test the Android classes, and once you're satisfied they're working, you can assume that they're working correctly.

Comment: Hey. I do not need to fully support for android. I just need to mock Log and Base64 class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need robolectric to mock Android classes: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html